# Get specific dict from a list dict and upload to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, json, list, dictionary

I'm recopilating some data from a connection every 2 seconds, and i want to put this data into a mysql database, my ouput data is this:

```
([{'TableNbr': 9, 'BegRecNbr': 9222359, 'TableName': b'Initial', 'IsOffset': 0, 'NbrOfRecs': 1, 'ByteOffset': None, 'RecFrag': [{'RecNbr': 9222359, 'TimeOfRec': datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 28, 1, 2, 17), 'Fields': {b'BattV': 11.994667053222656, b'PTemp_C': 23.523090362548828, b'BP_kPa': 100.7260971069336, b'Rain_mm': 0.0, b'Rain_mm_2': 0.0, b'AirTC': -39.08104705810547, b'AirTC2': 22.446022033691406, b'RH': 0.8168454170227051, b'RH2': 99.92742156982422, b'SlrkW': 0.000201545815798454, b'SlrkW_2': 0.0, b'SlrMJ': 4.0309163296115e-07, b'SlrMJ_2': 0.0, b'WS_ms': 0.0, b'WindDir': 83.36723327636719, b'Enc_RH': 58.200233459472656, b'T107_C': 26.024932861328125, b'SlrkW_3': nan, b'Raw_mV': nan, b'CS320_Temp': nan, b'CS320_X': nan, b'CS320_Y': nan, b'CS320_Z': nan, b'SlrMJ_3': nan}}]}], 0)
```

But i Only want de data of 'RecFrag' that have the Record Number, the time of the record and the raw data that is 'Fields' that have BattV, PTemp, etc.

I want to have this in a table that have the Record, date, and the other data, like

| Record | TimeStamp | BattV | PTemp | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxxx | xxxxxxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx | xxx |
| xxxxxx | xxxxxxxxx | xxxxx | xxxxx | xxx |

In Mysql

i tried converting the dict to json and there with pandas delete the columns that i don't want but when i convert to json i get a error because the time of the record have datetime.datetime('date')
`TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but from what I gather this is a start in the right direction.

```
import datetime

raw = "([{'TableNbr': 9, 'BegRecNbr': 9222359, 'TableName': b'Initial', 'IsOffset': 0, 'NbrOfRecs': 1, 'ByteOffset': None, 'RecFrag': [{'RecNbr': 9222359, 'TimeOfRec': datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 28, 1, 2, 17), 'Fields': {b'BattV': 11.994667053222656, b'PTemp_C': 23.523090362548828, b'BP_kPa': 100.7260971069336, b'Rain_mm': 0.0, b'Rain_mm_2': 0.0, b'AirTC': -39.08104705810547, b'AirTC2': 22.446022033691406, b'RH': 0.8168454170227051, b'RH2': 99.92742156982422, b'SlrkW': 0.000201545815798454, b'SlrkW_2': 0.0, b'SlrMJ': 4.0309163296115e-07, b'SlrMJ_2': 0.0, b'WS_ms': 0.0, b'WindDir': 83.36723327636719, b'Enc_RH': 58.200233459472656, b'T107_C': 26.024932861328125, b'SlrkW_3': nan, b'Raw_mV': nan, b'CS320_Temp': nan, b'CS320_X': nan, b'CS320_Y': nan, b'CS320_Z': nan, b'SlrMJ_3': nan}}]}], 0)"
raw = raw.replace('nan','None')
raw = eval(raw) # Evaluate to python dict
flat = []
recFrags = [raw[0][i]["RecFrag"] for i in range(len(raw[0]))][0]
for elements in recFrags:
    row = []
    nr = elements['RecNbr']
    tr = elements['TimeOfRec'].strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    row.append(nr)
    row.append(tr)
    for fields, values in elements["Fields"].items():
        row.append(values)
    flat.append(row)
print(flat)
```

Tell me if this helps or if I can clarify anything in my code.